# A question about horizontal lifts for an Ehresmann connection

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I was just reading the [Ehresmann connection wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection) and noticed that it defines an Ehresmann connection to be complete if a curve in the base can be horizontally lifted over its entire domain. I was under the impression that this was always true!

It is always true for the frame bundle of a vector bundle. In this case, [Gronwall's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) tells you that the paralell transport of a vector cannot blow up in finite time.

> **Question 1:**  Is it true that any principal bundle connection is complete? I haven't been able to prove this.
>
> **Question 2:**  Are there any interesting examples of Ehresmann connections which are not complete?

Comment: A comment just for completeness: I _think_ Ehresmann defined his connections to always be complete. And as soon as the distribution is complete, the bundle must be a fibre bundle. I guess the fact that 1) is true is just a generalisation of the fact that every homogeneous space is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: yes. See 19.6 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf).

Question 2: Not really. Most of them are of the kind of projecting an open disk to the open interval with the horizontal connection.

Remark: 17.9 of the same source proves that every fiber bundle admits a complete connection.
See also 17.11. 
The first published version of this is 9.9 of [this book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf)

Comment: I just wanted to say that I have been reading your topics in differential geometry notes and am learning a lot! Thanks for writing them

Comment: @Peter Michor do you know where I can read more about the relationship between the holonomy along a path and the homotopy class of this path? By the way, your books are really good, congratulations!!